# Convert String31 datetime format into datetime in Julia

Tags: datetime, julia, datetime-format, dataframes.jl

i have a **dataframe with Time colume with String31 format**. How can I convert this foramt into datetime?

[image]

I use Datetime method but it raised an error::

```
str_1=data_raw.Time[1,:]
DateTime(str_1, "yyyymmdd HHMMSS")
```

Error:

```
MethodError: no method matching Int64(::Vector{String31})
Closest candidates are:
(::Type{T})(!Matched::AbstractChar) where T<:Union{Int32, Int64}
@ Base char.jl:51
(::Type{T})(!Matched::AbstractChar) where T<:Union{AbstractChar, Number}
@ Base char.jl:50
(::Type{T})(!Matched::BigInt) where T<:Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8}
@ Base gmp.jl:36
```

Comment: Yoir date is in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format did you try `str_1=data_raw.Time[1,:]
DateTime(str_1, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")`

Comment: yes but same result :MethodError: no method matching Int64(::Vector{String31})

Comment: Sorry try: DateTime(str_1, dateformat"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")

Comment: @PaulMaxwell
i remove the **dateformat** and it convert it  into Datetime Format,
also i import DateTime like this : `import Dates.DateTime as Datetime`..
Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
DateTime.(str_1, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")
```

(note the `.` before `(` - it broadcasts `DateTime` over all elements of `str_1`)